# How do you manage an array in a template class (with the length of the array as a parameter) that has recursive function calls?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, recursion

This is a gist of a part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Exception
{ };

template <int row_length>
class IntContainer
{
private:
    int mem[row_length];
public:
    IntContainer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row_length; i++) mem[i] = i;
    }

    ~IntContainer() {}

    int get_det()
    {
        if (row_length == 2) return mem[0] + mem[1];
        else if (row_length == 1) return mem[0];
        else return get_cofactor();
    }

    int get_cofactor()
    {
        if (row_length == 1) throw Exception();
        IntContainer<row_length - 1> temp;
        return temp.get_det();
    }
};


int main()
{
    IntContainer<5> ic1;
    cout << ic1.get_det();
}
```

Compiling it with g++, i get the following error:

```
error: size '18446744073709551615' of array exceeds maximum object size '9223372036854775807'
11|  int mem[row_length];
```

What should I should do to manage the array without a compile error (i handle it properly in the functions)?

Comment: You need to specialize the template for `row_length` of 1 to ensure it doesn't attempt to recursively create instance with array size of 0 or less

Comment: How do you specialize the `row_length` param?

Answer (score 1):

##### Why this is happening

Even though `get_cofactor()` isn't called when `row_length` is 1 or 2, it still gets defined.

That in turn ends up defining `IntContainer` for `row_length` of size 1, 0, and eventually -1 (which wraps around to `MAX_INT`).

You can see this in the [diagnostic output](https://godbolt.org/z/MGWfbjexx) from gcc 11.2 on compiler explorer:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'class IntContainer<-1>':
<source>:30:38:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_cofactor() [with int row_length = 0]'
<source>:24:21:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_det() [with int row_length = 0]'
<source>:31:28:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_cofactor() [with int row_length = 1]'
<source>:24:21:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_det() [with int row_length = 1]'
<source>:31:28:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_cofactor() [with int row_length = 2]'
<source>:24:21:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
<source>:24:21:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_det() [with int row_length = 3]'
<source>:31:28:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_cofactor() [with int row_length = 4]'
<source>:24:21:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_det() [with int row_length = 4]'
<source>:31:28:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_cofactor() [with int row_length = 5]'
<source>:24:21:   required from 'int IntContainer<row_length>::get_det() [with int row_length = 5]'
<source>:39:24:   required from here
<source>:11:9: error: size '18446744073709551615' of array exceeds maximum object size '9223372036854775807'
   11 |     int mem[row_length];
      |         ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

##### C++17 `if constexpr` solution

If you're using C++17, then one solution is to turn your conditionals in `get_det()` into `if constexpr` statements

This suppresses the call to `get_cofactor`, which... should? suppress it being defined. I'm fuzzy on templates at that point. It may require template specialization if this isn't portable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Exception
{ };

template <int row_length>
class IntContainer
{
private:
    int mem[row_length];
public:
    IntContainer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row_length; i++) mem[i] = i;
    }

    ~IntContainer() {}

    int get_det()
    {
        if constexpr (row_length == 2) return mem[0] + mem[1];
        else if constexpr (row_length == 1) return mem[0];
        else return get_cofactor();
    }

    int get_cofactor()
    {
        if constexpr (row_length == 1) {
            throw Exception();
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            IntContainer<row_length - 1> temp;
            return temp.get_det();
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    IntContainer<5> ic1;
    cout << ic1.get_det();
}
```

##### Template specialization for the special recursion exit cases

FWIW I think rewriting this to use template specialization might be a little cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Exception
{ };

template <int row_length>
class IntContainer
{
private:
    int mem[row_length];
public:
    IntContainer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row_length; i++) mem[i] = i;
    }

    ~IntContainer() {}

    int get_det()
    {
        std::cout << "Entered get_det() row_length = " << row_length << '\n';
        return get_cofactor();
    }

    int get_cofactor()
    {
        std::cout << "Entered get_cofactor() row_length = " << row_length << '\n';
        IntContainer<row_length - 1> temp;
        return temp.get_det();
    }
};

template <>
int IntContainer<1>::get_det() {
    std::cout << "Entered specialized get_det() row_length = " << 1 << '\n';
    return mem[0];
}

template <>
int IntContainer<1>::get_cofactor() {
    std::cout << "Entered specialized get_cofactor() row_length = " << 1 << '\n';
    // throw Exception();
    return 0;
}

template <>
int IntContainer<2>::get_det() {
    std::cout << "Entered specialized get_det() row_length = " << 2 << '\n';
    return mem[0] + mem[1];
}


int main()
{
    IntContainer<5> ic1;
    cout << ic1.get_det() << '\n';

    IntContainer<1>{}.get_cofactor();
}
```

The above outputs

```
Entered get_det() row_length = 5
Entered get_cofactor() row_length = 5
Entered get_det() row_length = 4
Entered get_cofactor() row_length = 4
Entered get_det() row_length = 3
Entered get_cofactor() row_length = 3
Entered specialized get_det() row_length = 2
1
Entered specialized get_cofactor() row_length = 1
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `if constexpr` requires C++17, which some people may not be able to use yet. In which case the template specialization is the "old way" to fix the problem

Comment: You should also be using `if constexpr` in `get_cofactor` as that is where the recursion actually happens.

Comment: Does `template<> int IntContainer<1>::get_det()` work? I thought you had to specialize the entire enclosing class template and couldn't just specialize the definition of a member function.

Comment: @NathanPierson I ran it. Not sure if it's complete. I could be missing some edge cases. I know you can't do partial template specialization on the class, but this works as written. If you figure it out let me know.